# Can't have cubic resampleing with base map in QGIS 2.18.3

Tags: style, resampling

I want to display a raster with cubic resampling with base map, but it seems impossible in QGIS for some reason. 
I first change (in the style tab of the raster) the resampling to cubic and I get the proper result:

[image]

Then, I add base map, for example google hybrid, and the raster changes to nearest neighbor automatically, even though in the style tab it is still on cubic. The image looks like that:

[image]

I've tried different base maps and I get the same results.. it changes back to nearest neighbor and I can't change it to cubic. Also, even if I remove the base map, I can't change it to cubic, I need to restart QGIS for that.

Is there a way around it so I can have both cubic and base map?